# Error: $parse:syntax Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This error is driving me crazy and I need help.

> Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{
>   field }}.$error] starting at [{ field }}.$error].

## form-field.html

```
<div class='row form-group' ng-form="{{ field }}" ng-clase="{ 'has-error': {{ field }}.$dirty && {{ field }}.$invalid }">
    <label class='col-sm-2 control-label'> {{ field | labelCase }} <span ng-if='required'>*</span></label>
    <div class='col-sm-6' ng-switch='required'>

        <input ng-switch-when='true' ng-model='record[field][0]' type='{{ record[field][1] }}' class='form-control' required ng-change='update()' ng-blur='blurUpdate()' />

        <div class='input-group' ng-switch-default>
            <input ng-model='record[field][0]' type='{{ record[field][1] }}' class='form-control' ng-change='update()' ng-blur='blurUpdate()' />
            <span class='input-group-btn'>
                <button class='btn btn-default' ng-click='remove(field)'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle'></span></button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='col-sm-4 has-error' ng-show='{{ field }}.$dirty && {{ field }}.$invalid' ng-messages='{{ field }}.$error'>
        <p class='control-label' ng-messages='required'> {{ field | labelCase }} is required. </p>
        <p class='control-label' ng-repeat='(k, v) in types' ng-messages='{{ k }}'> {{ field | labelCase }} {{ v[1] }} </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

## directives.js

```
angular.module('ContactsApp')
    .value('FieldTypes', {
        text: ['Text', 'should be text'],
        email: ['Email', 'should be email'],
        number: ['Number', 'should be number'],
        date: ['Date', 'should be date'],
        datetime: ['Datetime', 'should be datetime'],
        time: ['Time', 'should be time'],
        month: ['Month', 'should be month'],
        week: ['Week', 'should be week'],
        url: ['URL', 'should be URL'],
        tel: ['Phone Number', 'should be phone number'],
        color: ['Color', 'should be color']
    })
    .directive('formField', function ($timeout, FieldTypes) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            templateUrl: 'views/form-field.html',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                record: '=',
                field: '@',
                live: '@',
                required: '@'
            },
            link: function ($scope, element, attr) {
                $scope.types = FieldTypes;

                $scope.remove = function (field) {
                    delete $scope.record[field];
                    $scope.blurUpdate();
                };

                $scope.blurUpdate = function () {
                    if ($scope.live !== 'false') {
                        $scope.record.$update(function (updatedRecord) {
                            $scope.record = updatedRecord;
                        });
                    }
                };
                var saveTimeout;
                $scope.update = function () {
                    $timeout.cancel(saveTimeout);
                    saveTimeout = $timeout($scope.blurUpdate, 1000);
                };
            }
        };
    });
```

## list.html

```
<p>
    <input type='search' class='form-control' placeholder='Search' ng-model='query'/>
</p>

<table class='table table-hover table-bordered'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat='field in fields' ng-click='sort(field)'>
                {{ field | labelCase }}
                <span ng-show='sort.field === field && !sort.order' class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'></span>
                <span ng-show='sort.field === field && sort.order' class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up'></span>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-click='show(contact.id)' ng-repeat='contact in contacts | filter: query | orderBy: sort.field : sort.order'>
            <td ng-repeat='field in fields'>
                {{ contact[field][0] }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Left to me, there's no syntax error. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: It's `ng-class` not ng-clase :-)

Comment: Why do you need to name the `ng-form` dynamically?

Comment: I think, and I stress think, it has to do with how ng-message is evaluating {field}.$error. What you want it to do is evaluate the field variable, add ".$error" THEN evaluate that whole expression to determine what error you have. Frankly, using a dynamic name (field) is strange to me, and it wouldn't surprise me if {field}.$dirty and {field}.$invalid aren't working correctly either

Comment: Essentially, because the expression you have in inside the ng-message attribute, angular ignores it and doesn't evaluate {{field}}. Which then causes ng-message to use "{{field}}.$error" as the key name, but { characters aren't allowed, causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `{{ field }}.$error` is evaluated the first time `{{ field }}` is not interpolated yet, so Angular interprets the first { as the beginning of an object declaration and the second one as a key. After the first digest cycle it works because it has been interpolated to `whatever.$error`.

There's absolutely no need for `{{ field }}`. Use `ng-form="form"`, replace `{{ field }}` with `form` and remove the parameter from `remove()` (no pun intended). The name of the form object is completely irrelevant.

Comment: i did make the change you asked me to and things are working now. but how do i know next time that i have to use `ng-form="form"` instead? where did that come from?

Comment: @siaw23 The `formField` directive has an isolated scope. That means that everything defined inside it stays inside it. `ng-form="whatever"` means that an object is put into that isolated scope under the name of `whatever`. Since every `form-field` has **its own** `whatever`, there's no need for different names.

Comment: thank you :). I have one question though. i'm new to angularjs. there's currently 1.4 and 2.0 versions of angular. which one would you advice i spend time on learning?

Comment: @siaw23 That's a highly subjective matter and also depends on a lot of variables. Keep in mind that most 3rd party components exist only for 1.x. and existing projects would be 1.x, too. Another important factor is that 2.0 is intended for newer browsers and preferably be used with TypeScript or ES6, which requires preprocessing. Since you are new to Angular I'd rather start with 1.4 for now and use it 2.0 style, i.e. think in components, use the `controller as` syntax etc. (Basically: Follow style guides and best practices).

Comment: wow! you convinced me so well. thanks for the info and advice. i'm sticking with 1.4. Thank you. TypeScript is not something i was to play with yet.

Answer (score 1):

When you wrap code in `{{ }}` in your html template, it tells angular that it needs to run the contents of that as an angular expression.  However, if you place that inside something that is already an angular expression, it will treat it as code, and throw a syntax error because it's not valid javascript.  Properties that start with `ng-` will be treated as angular expressions.  So where you have:

```
<div class='row form-group' ng-form="{{ field }}" ng-clase="{ 'has-error': {{ field }}.$dirty && {{ field }}.$invalid }">
```

It will treat the contents of `ng-clase` already as an angular exprssion, so the `{{ }}` are unnecessary.  It should be:

```
<div class='row form-group' ng-form="field" ng-class="{ 'has-error': field.$dirty && field.$invalid }">
```

I've reproduce your error with this [broken jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h1kv3uu8/) and fixed it with this [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h1kv3uu8/1/).

Edit: Actually, that line was not the cause of your error, because the type int `ng-clase` caused the expression to be ignored.  I think the line that was causing your error was:

```
 <div class='col-sm-4 has-error' ng-show='{{ field }}.$dirty && {{ field }}.$invalid' ng-messages='{{ field }}.$error'>
```

Which can be fixed in a similar way:

```
<div class='col-sm-4 has-error' ng-show='field.$dirty && field.$invalid' ng-messages='field.$error'>
```

Comment: `ng-form="field"` would break `record[field][0]`. _"Properties that start with ng- will be treated as angular expressions"_ is not correct. Neither are those properties nor will the content be inherently treated as expression.

Answer (score 0):

Something's missing as I don't see the directive being instantiated from list.html, so we can't get the whole picture here.

With that in mind, the way you're using {{field}} in form-field.html is weird: the directive receives field='@' which means it's a string yet in form-field.html you try to use it as an object. Check out the documentation on $compile that explains how parameters are passed to the directive's isolated scope pretty well.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile